# Vbulletin ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 38766: Duplicate entry

Tags: mysql, duplicates, backup

I have one Vbulettin Forum in RHC Opehshift Servers and I installed one module to backup automatically .

but when I want to import the SQL file to MySQL database i got this error:

> ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 38832: Duplicate entry '????????' for key
>   'tagtext'

So I need to know why this is happened.
The strange thing is when i do export the MySQL database by PHPMYADMIN It works correctly and the database is working on the server ( correct importing to new database),but when I use bash comand like :

```
mysql  -f -u $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME -p$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD  p1resta4shop3 > p1resta4shop3.sql
```

it's not working!!!?

Answer (score 0):

Open your `.sql` file in a text editor and try to find that line. Check it's **tagtext** and see if in `.sql` file there is another line with that **tagtext**.

Remove it and try to import again.